# $x^5+x-1=0\;,\;x\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given the following equation $$x^5+x-1=0\;,\;x\in\mathbb{R}$$

How to prove that (unevaluated)

$$x=\dfrac13\left(-1+\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{25}2-\dfrac{3\sqrt{69}}2}+\sqrt[3]{\dfrac12\left(25+3\sqrt{69}\right)}\right).$$

[$x^5+x-1=0\;,\;x\in\mathbb{R}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20x%5E5%2Bx-1%3D0%20over%20the%20reals)

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: you can factor the polynomial.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hint: $x^5 + x - 1 = (x^3 + x^2 -1)(x^2-x+1)$. Solving the first of these will give your solution.

Comment: And it should be established that the other four roots are not real, so that we may conclude $x$ is this number with certainty.